# Why does "require" behave differently when I am in the same directory or a parent directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

While testing some code I came across a situation that I can not explain.  After hours of googling I couldn't really figure out the right questions to ask.  Any help in the right direction or the correct terminology would be appreciated..!

So,.. When I require a file that is located in the same working directory, I am able to do the fallowing:

```
const { ports, keys } = require('./activeConfig');
console.log(ports, keys, activeConfig);
```

In this situation `ports, keys,` and `activeConfig` are all defined and i can use the module as if I had done:

```
const { ports, keys } = require('./activeConfig');
const activeConfig = require('./activeConfig');
console.log(ports, keys, activeConfig);
```

However if I try to do the exact same thing from an external directory like so:

```
const { ports, keys } = require('../../config/activeConfig');
```

or

```
const { ports, keys } = require('./config/activeConfig');
```

`activeConfig` is no longer defined and I get an error.

Why is this behavior different depending on the location that I am importing from? Or does this have to do with the way I am exporting the module?
I would like to keep my code nice and tidy, so I would prefer to avoid having to write the second `require`.  Is there perhaps a different method to do this all in one line?

The module I am trying to require is a Singleton with the fallowing code:

```
const database = {...}
const keys = {...}
const ports = {...}
const tokens = {...}

module.exports = activeConfig = (() => {
    let _database = database;
    let _keys = keys;
    let _ports = ports;
    let _tokens = tokens;

    return {
        setDatabase: (value) => {
            if (value) {...}
            return activeConfig;
        },
        setKeys: (value) => {
            if (value) {...}
            return activeConfig;
        },
        setPorts: (value) => {
            if (value) {...}
            return activeConfig;
        },
        setTokens: (value) => {
            if (value) {...}
            return activeConfig;
        },
        updateConfig: () => {
               ...
            return activeConfig;
        },
        get database() {
            return _database;
        },
        get keys() {
            return _keys;
        },
        get ports() {
            return _ports;
        },
        get tokens() {
            return _tokens;
        },
        set database(value) {...},
        set keys(value) {...},
        set ports(value) {...},
        set tokens(value) {...}
    };
})();
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to mix ES6 module syntax and CommonJS (module.exports)... which may result in weirdness. I think you need to pick one and stick to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that your `activeConfig` module is declaring an implicit global variable.

The line:

```
module.exports = activeConfig = (() => { //...
```

This will leak the variable `activeConfig` to the global scope when you first require the module.

Afterwards, when you require the module again in other places, NodeJS will simply pull the previously exported object [form the cache](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), and it won't execute the assignment.

Try running your code in strict mode, add `"use strict"` at the top of `activeConfig.js` and you will see that it won't let you leak the global variable.

Leaking globals is bad, I would instead recommend you to put a reference to the same instance in the object you export, so it can be "destructured" when you require it.

For example:

```
"use strict"
module.exports = (() => {
    // ....
    return {
       // ....
        get instance() {
            return this;
        },
    };
})();
```

And then when you require it:

```
const { ports, keys, instance: activeConfig } = require('./config/activeConfig');
```